# Js cookies : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, cookies

The error is thrown when i set a cookie with a date :

```
var COOKIE = {

    setCookie: function(name, value, expdate) {
        'use strict';

        var str = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
        str +=';expires=' + expdate.toUTCString();
        alert("in");
        console.log(expdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = str;
    } // End of setCookie() function

};

window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
   COOKIE.setCookie('username', 'John', Mon 29 Aug 2016 11:40:00 UTC ); // date
};
```

But it doesn't if i use a number of days :

```
var COOKIE = {

    setCookie: function(name, value, numdays) {
        'use strict';

         var cookieDate = new Date();
       cookieDate.setDate(cookieDate.getDate() + numdays);

        var str = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
        str +=';expires=' + cookieDate.toGMTString();
        alert("in");
        console.log(cookieDate.toGMTString());
        document.cookie = str;
    } // End of setCookie() function

};

window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
   COOKIE.setCookie('username', 'John', 1 ); // day
};
```

I respected the format expected by official doc. What's going on here?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the debugger. It points you to the line:

```
COOKIE.setCookie('username', 'John', Mon 29 Aug 2016 11:40:00 UTC );
```

`Mon 29 Aug 2016 11:40:00 UTC` is not valid JavaScript. Maybe it was meant to be in quotes as a string.

Comment: Whothehellisthat - I've already tried this but error still there;

Comment: The error is the same. I replaced the date with a variable of type date and no error anymore.

Comment: If you change the code so that you pass in a date, it works fine: `COOKIE.setCookie('username', 'John', new Date("Mon 29 Aug 2016 11:40:00 UTC")); // date`

Comment: A jsFiddle would be nice so we can see exactly what code you're running.